# Ceilometer identity.authenticate.failure

Tags: openstack, ceilometer

The command "ceilometer sample-list -m identity.authenticate.failure" give a response with a `resource_id` like `:openstack:b64d526d-9624-4f3c-b986-3d6e275d0758`.

- What is this ID and it refers to what?
- How can I have the user ID that belongs to this resource ID ?

The output is :

```
+------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------+--------+------+----------------------------+
| Resource ID                                    | Name                          | Type  | Volume | Unit | Timestamp                  |
+------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------+--------+------+----------------------------+
| openstack:85b53cba-3b11-4019-ac70-087d7412bf15 | identity.authenticate.failure | delta | 1.0    | user | 2015-05-25T13:10:18.848000 |
| openstack:c23f883d-0f6d-45a5-be7d-9ea2fc53c100 | identity.authenticate.failure | delta | 1.0    | user | 2015-05-25T12:15:28.930000 |
| openstack:b64d526d-9624-4f3c-b986-3d6e275d0758 | identity.authenticate.failure | delta | 1.0    | user | 2015-05-25T12:13:03.352000 |
| openstack:d8eae00c-76b0-4b9d-8e53-26f6e849cb83 | identity.authenticate.failure | delta | 1.0    | user | 2015-05-25T11:56:53.429000 |
| openstack:faacab54-f3eb-43eb-861c-93f45f0b2ada | identity.authenticate.failure | delta | 1.0    | user | 2015-05-25T11:56:42.232000 |
| openstack:6303221f-f17a-4d82-9c43-83f0d9dc58c2 | identity.authenticate.failure | delta | 1.0    | user | 2015-05-25T11:01:52.166000 |
| openstack:22a1f0a5-6109-4554-9a4a-178452667e18 | identity.authenticate.failure | delta | 1.0    | user | 2015-05-25T11:01:47.553000 |
| openstack:c1fc85b3-5257-41d0-8bfa-67c2eb367f79 | identity.authenticate.failure | delta | 1.0    | user | 2015-05-25T09:56:58.225000 |
| openstack:4e79a88d-bda0-4438-ac76-81fab2a5e49d | identity.authenticate.failure | delta | 1.0    | user | 2015-05-25T09:56:29.472000 |
+------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------+--------+------+----------------------------+
```

Comment: Can you please post the complete output you get??

Comment: Thank you for your help . I had posted the completer output in my question above .